# Grails Spring Security 2.0 Active Directory authentication using user's group

Tags: spring, security, authentication, grails, active-directory

I used **dsquery** for receive informations about my login in AD and I received information about name of group which I belong.

-name

```
CN=Surname Name I,OU=CITY,OU=FOLDER,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

-group

```
CN=Name-of-Group Using Spaces, OU=Department ,OU=Folder_two,OU=Folder_one,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com
```

So, I want to make accepting login only for me or users who consist in my group (
CN=Name-of-Group Using Spaces
). Here is my

```
Config.groovy

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'Surname Name I,OU=CITY,OU=FOLDER,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://server:xxx/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'DC=domain,DC=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=user))"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/view/index'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions= false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames=['ldapAuthProvider']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Annotation'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/view/index':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
// '/view/index':['ROLE_Name-of-Group Using Spaces'] - this is what I tryed to use also and Its not working
]
```

this is working config, but the problem is that any user from domain has access.

Comment: Have you tried variations on `...ldap.search.base`?  Another option would be to add a `@Secured(['ROLE_Name-of-Group Using Spaces'])` annotation to all controllers.  However, this would still allow everyone to authenticate.  Users not in the specific group would see only the 'denied' page.

Comment: Using `@Secured` doesn't help. I'm getting `"Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page."` message. Also, I tried to use `"Name-of-Group Using Spaces"` in `ldap.search.base` - this solution also is not working.

Answer (score 1):

here is solution:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'Surname Name I,OU=CITY,OU=FOLDER,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://server:xxx/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'DC=domain,DC=com'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="(&(sAMAccountName={0})(|(memberOf=CN=Name-of-Group #1 Using Spaces, OU=Department ,OU=Folder_two,OU=Folder_one,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=Name-of-Group #2 Using Spaces, OU=Department ,OU=Folder_two,OU=Folder_one,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com)))" 

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true    
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames=['ldapAuthProvider'] 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation" 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [    
'/**': ['isFullyAuthenticated()'] 
]
```

- authentication only for members of groups "Name-of-Group #1 Using Spaces" and "Name-of-Group #2 Using Spaces". No need "%20"